# How to replace value in field with value from another field if incoming data is null in vb for applications

Tags: ms-access, vba

Using: MS Access 2013 (Form)
Pieces:  tbListAmount (coming from a product description table/form)
         tbAmount (coming from a quote form, value is entered manually)
         tbDiscount (coming from a quote form, value is entered manually)

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

*(ListAmount field on form)*
If the data coming into [ListAmount] is null, 
Then populate [ListAmount] with value from [Amount]
End If

*(Amount field on form)*
=[Amount]-([Amount]*[Discount]) *(to find the amount with discount applied)*

NB - I am a total newb to programming.  I have scoured both SO and the net for the answer, and couldn't make it go on my own.  So I am hoping the SO experts on here can help!

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to this myself, but having has a similar issue, I think it would go something like this:

```
If IsNull(Me.ListAmount.Value) = True Then
Me.ListAmount.Value = Me.Amount.Value
End If
```

Where you put it depends on how ListAmount gets populated. If becomes populated when the form is loaded, then it should go in the On Load of the Form. If it is populated after another field is interacted with, you should put this code in as an AfterUpdate event of that control.